# about SQL Row filter

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have this type of table of database in sql

```
id | state | msg | userid | time |
1  |unread | hi  |    1   | time |
2  |unread |hello|    1   | time | 
3  |unread | hi  |    2   | time |
4  | read  | hi  |    2   | time |
```

I have conduction for print rows

```
Where state=unread
```

Now output is

```
= userid 1 send you 'hi'
= userid 1 send you 'hello'
= userid 2 send you 'hi'
```

But I want to output this way

```
= userid 1 send you 'hello'
= userid 2 send you 'hi'
```

Remove same userid row and select last one only (using php with sqli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.state, a.msg, a.userid, a.time 
FROM tableA a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT a.userid, MAX(a.id) id 
            FROM tableA a 
            WHERE a.state = 'unread'
            GROUP BY a.userid
           ) AS b ON a.userid = b.userid AND a.id = b.id;
```